# Rails gem to prepend a couple of lines to application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sprockets

I'd like to write a gem that prepends some license tags to a rails app's JavaScript files after they've been through the asset pipeline. Does anyone know an example gem that does something similar that I can look at?

I'm guessing I can do this with a Sprockets post-processor. Since this is the first ruby gem I've ever written, I need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good example here - https://github.com/jsuder/sprockets-strict-mode